# spidev0.0 not showing with enc28j60 and raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, spi, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to setup SPI with the ETH Click (a board for the enc28j60) with the raspberry pi 4 model b and pi 3 click shield.

when I set the overlay for enc28j60 in my /boot/config.txt only spidev0.1 appears when I do the command ls -l /dev/spi*:

crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 May 26 11:40 /dev/spidev0.1

My /boot/config.txt

```
#Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=enc28j60,int_pin=6
```

I'm using:
CE0 - GPIO8
MISO - GPIO9
MOSI - GPIO10
SCLK - GPIO11
INT - GPIO6

If I remove the dtoverlay spidev0.0 appears.

My raspbian version when running the command: cat /etc/os-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: So, what is the question? How SPI works? How chip selects are being allocated? Hint: what you describe is what I would expect on properly working system.

Comment: I was trying to use the python spidev library: https://pypi.org/project/spidev/ but when I do spi = spidev.SpiDev() and spi.open(0,0) for SPI bus 0, device 0 I get IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I thought this error was because /dev/spidev0.0 was not appearing.

Comment: For example in the README here: https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev it says the open method 'Connects to the specified SPI device, opening /dev/spidev<bus>.<device>'. I assumed this library was compatible with the enc28j60 as I based my code off of this repo: https://github.com/KroMignon/enc28j60-rpi

Comment: @0andriy Do you know how I can set up spi with the enc28j60? I want to be able to write to registers on the enc28j60 (slave) from the raspberry pi (master) through SPI in order to send packets. Is it possible to access the chip select 0 with the spidev library or is there another library you would recommend?

Comment: You have kernel driver which does it for you. Check _lsmod_.